# Убрать автосоздание файлов в Symfony

Tags: symfony

Подскажите, можно ли в symfony, при создании контроллера через bin/console make..., отключить автосоздание шаблона twig ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bin/console make:controller --help`

> You can also generate the controller alone, without template with this option:
> php bin/console make:controller --no-template